# Get user current position with gps/network android MapView

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview

Hello I've been using this guide to determine the locationof the user: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

and my current code looks like this:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            test = new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude()*1000000, (int)location.getAltitude()*1000000);
            mapController.animateTo(test);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

I only get error and the app shuts down though when I'm using this activity.

Thankful for help

Comment: Can you post your logcat traces ?

Comment: I only get the error when running on the mobile since the emulator doesnt have any wifi/gps connection. Is there a defualt error log that creates in the mobile?

Comment: when u connect ur mobile with ur system and run it, the log will be present inside the logcat of eclipse. Please paste that.

Comment: I've connected my phone to my computer now and I've enabled usb troubleshooting. But nothing under "devices" appears in the DDMS tab and when I run the app on the phone logcat don't log anything.

Comment: after connecting to ur computer and give run, is it running in device?

Comment: Run as in "run <projectname>" ? Because when that buttom is pressed the emulator comes up as a "devices" but not my mobile.

Comment: http://img138.imageshack.us/f/errorvl.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I didn't instantiate mapContoller :>. But I've another problem now. which I will post in another question.

Answer (score 0):

PLease confirm that you have alloted the following permission to your manifest file

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: <manifest.....                                                   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission> 

</manifest>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are executing this code in the device

try this on device

Setting -> Location -> Use GPS

AND

Setting -> Application Settings -> Development -> Allow Mock Location