# Get current coordinates

Tags: android, sms, locationmanager

Im writing an application that supposed to send coordinates in an SMS, but I've been struggling a bit with understanding how to get the coordinates.

At the moment I'm using this

```
  LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
  Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  longitude = location.getLongitude();
  latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

And then i pass the long and lat into the text, but this only gives me the last know location i guess?

Can anyone tell me how to get the current location?

Regards
/Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a LocationListener and pass it to the LocationManager like this: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationManager.getBestProvider(fine, true),
                minTime, 0, listenerFine);`
You will get your lat/long updates from the listener in onLocationChanged()

Comment: thanks, I've tried that as well, but what i couldn't understand with the onLocationChange() change is when it runs the code within. Is it whenever the potion change?

Comment: in the code above 'minTime' specifies the milliseconds to wait before requesting an update and the following '0' specifies the distance to wait from the previous location before requesting an update. If you passed 0,0,listenerFine... you would request updates constantly. If you have a breakpoint in onLocationChanged you will break on it frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Please referred Below Link it may be Help You 
[Get user current position with gps/network android MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015202/get-user-current-position-with-gps-network-android-mapview)
or 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html