# simplest way to get users coordinates and compare the distance from desired location

Tags: java, android, location, coordinates

What would be the simplest way to get the user coordinates? I only need them to see if they match up with my desired coordinates and they do not have to match up perfectly the user can be within 0.3 of a mile

i have tried to use google maps v1 and v2 but it was getting more complex than it should be since i only need it to compare with some set coordinates

so what i need help with is to get the user's coordinates(location) and then get their distance from my desired location which is (-80.000000,40.000000) and see if they are within the radius (480~ 0.3 mile)

would someone be able to listen the steps i need to take in order to accomplish this?

Comment: If its a fixed location (or a small set of fixed locations) just use a Geofence.

Answer (score 1):

To get user coordinates, you will need to use [LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881043/1008011) to give you more details how you can go about acquiring the coordinates. Based on that answer, you create a location manager:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
longitude = location.getLongitude();
latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

then you create and attach a `locationListener` object to the location manager:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.getBestProvider(fine, true), minTime, 0, listenerFine);
```

---

Once you have the coordinates, you can then use [Geofencing](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html), here's a short snippet from the documentation about creating and monitoring Geofences:

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
    .setRequestId("geofenceRequestID")
    .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, 480f)
    .setExpirationDuration("300000") // duration is in millis (5mins)
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    .build());
```

Here's more [details](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder) on using Geofence.Builder.

Comment: thank you for the steps; however i am already getting an error with the first line of code and it says "inconvertible types; cannot cast java.lang.String to android.location.LocationManager"

Comment: You should use `getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)` in the first line.

Comment: @damian thanks, i have updated the code to reflect the change.

Comment: @chornge since I am using Marshmallow i have to request permission but then it says "cannot resolve symbol" for `longitude` and `latitude` i turned it into a double is that fine?

Comment: yes, you can use any double value for the longitude and latitude, u can use `location.getLongitude()` from the location manager as well.

Comment: okay thank you now how would I attach the locationlistener object to the locationmanager?

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(fine, true), minTime, 0, listenerFine);

Comment: you just changed it from lm to locationManager? to clairfy, how would I attach a locationListener object to the locationManager?

Comment: in my answer, i state how to create a location manager object (i named it lm) and then below it i showed how to attach a location listener object to it.

Comment: ah ok thank you! I am getting an error saying it cannot find symbol `fine` `minTime` and `listenerFine`

Comment: I also got another one saying it cannot find `Geofence`